# How to send bitmap image in attachment in automatic Email Android App

Tags: android, email-attachments, email

Below is the code where i am composing my email. But here, i am not getting any option to attach my bitmap image from SDcard.

```
private Message createMessage(String email, String subject, String messageBody, Session session) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("tutorials@tiemenschut.com", "AutoScreenShot Application"));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email, email));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(messageBody);
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following set of code, this worked for me.

This helped me to sent the attachment.

```
private Message createMessage(String email, String subject, String messageBody, Session session) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("tutorials@tiemenschut.com", "AutoScreenShot Application"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email, email));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(messageBody);
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String file = "/sdcard/Pictures/screenshot.png";
        String fileName = "screenshot.png";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        return message;
    }
```